# Count the number of records after a pagination

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I'm using pagination to retrieve just 10 results by page.
My query is like this in `querydsl`

```
query.offset(pageNumber*pageSize).limit(pageSize).list(..);

search.Execution time: 69 ms
```

But i have also to count the total numbers of pages So I have to count the whole query

```
query.count();

count.Execution time: 4187 ms
```

As you see the count query take mutch more time and slow down my user's request

So how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Yes it will as it is an additional query adding more time to the request. How fast it actually is depends on your query, your database, do you have indexes etc.

Comment: So there is no other choice to count other than adding a additional query ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You will have to issue at least 2 queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can do separate query only for count that would speed up the process.

Comment: i didn't understand can you explain me more ?

Comment: Yes one query will be pulling only paginated records and other query will fetch the total count as per your requirement.

Comment: yes this is what i do now i'm looking for solution to do just one request to avoid adding more time to the request.

Comment: But you didnt helped me yet